# CV2 and Pillow give different image shape

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a black and white image that I am loading into python. If I use pillow or cv2 I get two different answers for the dimension of the NumPy array that is created. I understand that channel ordering (RGB vs BGR) is different from openCV and pillow but I don't think that's what's going on here

Is my image 2 dimensions as pillow represents it. Does this mean that openCV duplicates the values into a 3D array?

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = 'path/to/file.png'

#using pillow
img = Image.open(path)
img.size #(500,500)
img.mode # L
arr = np.array(img)
arr.shape #(500,500)

#using cv2
image = cv2.imread(path)
image.shape #(500,500,3)
```

If I run `file` in a bash terminal

```
$ file 'path/to/image.png'
path/to/image: PNG image data, 500 x 500, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
```

Comment: What are the `//` doing? Are they supposed to be comments?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. Forgot which language I was in for a second. The comments show what the result of the line is

Comment: use imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

Comment: mode "L" is equivalent to grayscale, so one channel, cv2.imread("pathimage", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) is equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cv2.imread` function takes two arguments: filename, and flag. The flag is set to `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` (or 1) by default. PIL on the other hand automatically loads your image in grayscale mode, 'L'. If you want your cv2 image to work the same way, do:

```
image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

You can also convert your grayscale PIL image to 3 channels:

```
img = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

cv2 requires explicit specification of grayscale, otherwise it always decompresses as color (BGR).

```py
>>> import cv2
>>> x = cv2.imread('lena.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
>>> x.shape
(512, 512, 1)
```

This is a bit odd, especially if the image is grayscale.

```py
>>> cv2.imwrite('lena_gray.jpeg', x);  # save as grayscale JPEG
>>> x2 = cv2.imread('lena_gray.jpeg')
>>> x2.shape
(512, 512, 3)
```

Conversion of grayscale to RGB is done by duplication of the value into each color channel. E.g. original white (255) becomes (255,255,255), black (0) becomes (0,0,0), etc.

```py
>>> cv2.imread('lena_gray.jpeg')
array([[[162, 162, 162],
        [161, 161, 161],
        [160, 160, 160],
        ...
        [102, 102, 102],
        [104, 104, 104],
        [107, 107, 107]]], dtype=uint8)
>>> cv2.imread('lena_gray.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
array([[ 162, 161, 160, ... ],
       ...
       [ ... , 102, 104, 107]], dtype=uint8)
```

When working with grayscale, pay attention to third dimension. While PIL returns 2D matrix, cv2 has the third dimension of size one. The latter is of course more practical as it unifies working with RGB and grayscale.

```py
>>> y = np.array(Image.open('lena_gray.jpeg'))
>>> y.shape
(512, 512)
>>>
>>> import cv2
>>> x = cv2.imread('lena.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
>>> x.shape
(512, 512, 1)
```

Comment: I don't know what version of OpenCV you're using there but the current release, and all releases for the past years, mapped single-channel `cv::Mat` to a 2D numpy array of shape (H,W), not (H,W,1)